# azure storage upload image file and get its url to display with img tag

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, azure-storage

I want use azure file storage to store image file

and i can upload image file with below code

```
...
const uploadBlobResponse = await blockBlobClient.uploadFile('./test.png');
console.log('Blob was uploaded successfully. requestId: ', uploadBlobResponse);
```

And output is

```
Blob was uploaded successfully. requestId:  {
  etag: '"0x8D8FCCEC050FDB7"',
  lastModified: 2021-04-11T09:46:59.000Z,
  contentMD5: <Buffer a6 c1 b2 ef 44 0d 59 d2 33 43 ea c3 03 06 3f e3>,
  clientRequestId: 'c261dccb-1b2f-4802-9768-c98bb59cc8b4',
  requestId: '686eda5f-301e-00c0-49b7-2ead12000000',
  version: '2020-06-12',
  versionId: undefined,
  date: 2021-04-11T09:46:58.000Z,
  isServerEncrypted: true,
  encryptionKeySha256: undefined,
  encryptionScope: undefined,
  errorCode: undefined,
  'content-length': '0',
  server: 'Windows-Azure-Blob/1.0 Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0',
  'x-ms-content-crc64': 'F99Vk4U+TkE=',
  body: undefined
}
```

So, I cannot get the image's public URL.

How I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`BlockBlobClient`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/javascript/api/@azure/storage-blob/blockblobclient?view=azure-node-latest) has a [`url`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/javascript/api/@azure/storage-blob/blockblobclient?view=azure-node-latest#url) property that will give you the URL of the blob. Something like:

```
const uploadBlobResponse = await blockBlobClient.uploadFile('./test.png');
console.log('Blob was uploaded successfully. requestId: ', uploadBlobResponse);
console.log('Blob URL: ', blockBlobClient.url);
```

However, even though the URL is the public URL of the blob it may still result in `404 (Not Found)` error if the blob is inside a blob container with `Private` ACL. You will need to use a `Shared Access Signature` URL of the blob with at least `Read` permission to view the blob by its URL.